# Dockers Cassandra node showing UJ

Tags: docker, cassandra

1.I have successfully installed Cassandra in dockers and i am using Linux-Ubuntu Virtual Machine.

2.For the execution i have used two VM of Linux-Ubuntu machine and made one seed node and one other node to join the seed node. Now it is not still showing UJ and not yet showing UN. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in the other node joining the seed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzjaT.png)

Commands:

```
$ docker run --name node2 -d -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=192.168.1.52 -p 7000:7000 cassandra:latest
$ docker run --name node4 -d -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=192.168.1.53 -p 7000:7000 -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=192.168.1.52 cassandra:latest
```

Comment: Hi, Guys i myself solved this issue. Just need to use cassandra:2 and not cassandra:latest. Because the latest version still fixing this issue i think.

Comment: Hi @user9371612 post your comment as an  answer so that other users with the same issues can find it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer : Just changed my Cassandra version to 2 and then it worked fine. Using dockers and Cassandra was quick and simple

Answer (score 0):

UJ is combination of Status and State of the node in the Cassandra cluster.

We can view it using the command `nodetool status`. The first column is the one which shows Status and State and also tells what the letters stands for.

In this case U means **UP** and J means **Joining**.

When we add a new node to the Cassandra cluster it takes some time to reach normal state. Before that it's in Joining state.